# Merge two tuple type?(eg. merge [any] and [any, any] to [any, any, any])

Tags: arrays, typescript, types

There are three types.

How to merge `A` and `B`?

typescript: 3.6.3

```js
type A = [any]
type B = [any, any]
type C = [any, any, any]
```

Is there some way to merge `[any]` and `[any, any]`?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking here. Can you add more detail? A full example showing how you want to use this might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to be able to take two tuple types and concatenate them in the type system, so that the type `Concat<[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]>` evaluates to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.  There's nothing built into the TypeScript type system that allows you to do this.  You can write things yourself that get close, but a straightforward recursive definition is [not supported](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980).

---

There is a library called [ts-toolbelt](https://pirix-gh.github.io/ts-toolbelt/) which uses some recursive types to [implement `Concat`](https://pirix-gh.github.io/ts-toolbelt/modules/_tuple_concat_.html#concat).  These recursive types are apparently either supported by TypeScript or soon-to-be supported, as the ts-toolbelt library [will become part of the tests for building TypeScript itself](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33810).

---

If you don't want to use a library there are different ways to proceed.  I built the following thing which supports tuples up to length 30 or so using some type manipulation and a small program to output the tedious parts:

```
type Add = [['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['25', '26', '27', '28', '29'], ['26', '27', '28', '29'], ['27', '28', '29'], ['28', '29'], ['29']];
type Sub = [['0'], ['1', '0'], ['2', '1', '0'], ['3', '2', '1', '0'], ['4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['13', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['14', '13', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['15', '14', '13', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['16', '15', '14', '13', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['17', '16', '15', '14', '13', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['18', '17', '16', '15', '14', '13', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['19', '18', '17', '16', '15', '14', '13', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['20', '19', '18', '17', '16', '15', '14', '13', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['21', '20', '19', '18', '17', '16', '15', '14', '13', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['22', '21', '20', '19', '18', '17', '16', '15', '14', '13', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['23', '22', '21', '20', '19', '18', '17', '16', '15', '14', '13', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['24', '23', '22', '21', '20', '19', '18', '17', '16', '15', '14', '13', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['25', '24', '23', '22', '21', '20', '19', '18', '17', '16', '15', '14', '13', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['26', '25', '24', '23', '22', '21', '20', '19', '18', '17', '16', '15', '14', '13', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['27', '26', '25', '24', '23', '22', '21', '20', '19', '18', '17', '16', '15', '14', '13', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['28', '27', '26', '25', '24', '23', '22', '21', '20', '19', '18', '17', '16', '15', '14', '13', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0'], ['29', '28', '27', '26', '25', '24', '23', '22', '21', '20', '19', '18', '17', '16', '15', '14', '13', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0']];
type Tup = [[], [0], [0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]];
type Idx<T, K, N = never> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : N;
type Concat<T extends readonly any[], U extends readonly any[]> =
    T extends any ? U extends any ?
    Tup[Add[T["length"]][U["length"]]] extends infer V ?
    { [K in keyof V]: Idx<T, K, Idx<U, Idx<Sub, K>[T["length"]]>> } :
    never : never : never
```

Let's see if it works:

```
type Six = Concat<[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]>
// type Six = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

type Union = Concat<["a"] | [1, 2], ["b"] | [3, 4]>
// type Union = ["a", "b"] | ["a", 3, 4] | [1, 2, "b"] | [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

There are likely a lot of edge cases, especially around [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#readonly-tuples), [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types), and [rest](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types) tuple elements, and of course arrays that are not tuples:

```
type Oops = Concat<readonly [1?], [2, 3, ...string[]]>;
// type Oops = [] | [1 | undefined] | [1 | undefined, 3 | 2] | 
// [1 | undefined, 3 | 2, 3] | [1 | undefined, 3 | 2, 3, never] |
// [1 | undefined, 3 | 2, 3, never, never] | 
// [1 | undefined, ... 4 more ..., never] | ... 22 more ... | [...]
```

so I'd test very carefully before using this.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.7-Beta&ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=1#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-RLAxLgxLQxLwxLIxLXZ6M164-GqHmqAWqEWqCWqGWqBWqNGmDK5XmC0WS2WK1WJRmTQac3nSAXSEXSCXSGXSBXSOP3XGs1R643m63253u72ZAnxUPk+LR2njZOs6QZwb54vl6v15uazu93GD3Gj3GJ6CjGl7iiOqbiuOhoGg+T5Wgar4Gu+BqftudZxvucaHnGx5xqeQrDim4pjumMHTgas4vgab4Gh+cZfuhbqYW62Furhbr4YK4HEbe0rQcasEUc+CHUUhtEofRaFuj+bp-m6AFukBMY3pBpECeRFrCTaokOuJLqSW634Yb+WH-jhgF4cBfYkXeZFmkJ8HaXaYlOhJboMdJxmyaZ8nmYplkxlB94aXxlEic5umufp7lST6XkBj5IZ+RGAV9vxfGCZpjl8YhkV8XRMWGYxfomSxZlsRZHFWWeU72VlfFURFfHIdF1axTKMkJWVvkVf5VUxo+DkNeFfE0VFfGoUVnlMaVQblWGlVRtVQq5lpOU6c1ekTQZnpGTN3ndUlvUpf1aWNaNLn5W5bVTXF+1dXNPULX1S0Dblm3jZWO0yntJUHY9R3PSdr1pWNV2tTKHl3X9D0yqxQMykpaUtdthW7cVMrMQDMoKcDMqcWu12Q+1u7xTKcmAzK7EgzVk3o9NMPk4lOPJYjqVnlut0dWTTbM22rNduzQq1gzmOzXD81U4t+PLdz91M4dLPHWzp0c1jEtPVLL0yzGvOK-zyuC6rwvw1reM9rLBsI0bNPC9TOt9jbDsc9G9ATDkXIwEszgCiKstZqKusGnKgd9o2wfiqHZ4FuHxoh7LRYx3GEfSlHQolonA7J3Hkey2WGeJuKsd8fHMYVvnSYXlnbop37gUQdKFfipnRfZyXucDRm47l1e0ot9Kxexh3aUPl3DeCk3feFwPbdD6n-s5qPvGCj3YGV9KSc1zn88DbOi9qdK3dEdKBdV63W-tzvZ1Ddmdl8WPPHXr3gr9+enq12nhZrRKe93xOy+rxPuvQUm937bzrqDEa+Yb6DXUrZVSj9G7P1foPAO-tVzLkXPOX+cD74AOPlxYBoD+zgM-oTPKxYoFzhgfveBh9x6TxftPN+JDL4QNpltUsG0v7ZR-iFTMB9BRHyfmvZuzDUGl0dpOKC64MFUOwfw2qeCEHSkAYQsRZ8Z4Xznuw4WO5pGcJXNwhc39Vp1QyoI4RSDRFT00SwnMkiOb1n0UTchH0LpOWGvVW+uD-4qJXgQ0+G9q5gLYZ-BsGMRY3VRuDdxlDPHQO8bAixdChEMOQeI2eaDdbNkbM476G5DFyISdQpJtDlH0MQRPDJdiJHDw5q2XJkSXEQzcVwpqPCvGhUUUvfxaigkgJCawnR4T2yNJ5vktGX1PpGI6SY3hZi+LlL8ZU1RgSiFDIcfUu2ksWziwiaLKJxNWmyOMVgmhf90ppKqYwlBWTHHC27J2MZ+y8kkwMTM4p60Fk4JSRU65ayRFAI0cE8+oSRmW03E83Z4z5aky5pzGJ5ZLrxO+V0vh5iBGpKsdUmxTDan3I7m7TkEgAAqSwwACjaMKallAaVMGFHSultKoCMtZcyhlTL2XcvpTINl-KuX8pZQKnlgrhWColTy8VoqZUit5cQOVkrFVSs5bKpV6rWXSuVdqpVWqNU6tlXqtVxqDXytNfqi1Kq+WWvNSasVqrbWOptUap1dq3VmptZ691uqHVetdf6l1fqg3usDd6sN-qOXWvDcGiNhrfXRoTbGuVoak0xr9SmtNiaY0ZqzbmpNObU15uzfGwtpbM3JuJR7CQABJGoCBCCksoAAaUoAAOWkPCCoPBpBNqgBABAwAICrBKAAawgCADA6woCkqgM0adxAm1WAAFxQFbe7XIRhygNr7QOodNQShVFqA0JoeAsAgBGJQbQO7B3DqgIeuoWBGhQFPee3gKBBBQE-dO69e6SgvtnVAK9-ab37ufWe2dH6v3krAMQXkNRiCktCPUIdgxgAAAtLD0GINoJDKH0OYasMB39UABjrD+FAAAahBgQX6oAAG8ZC9oGFAMdE6p0UfoCu2t9bG1QBbVAbjhBtCUEE17ZwzaeAIdw0MfDoweDdoAL5QCXZBz9nblNQHUyuzt2QgA)